# Is there possible to export XML from Final Cut Pro without open the Application?

Tags: final-cut-pro

Is it possible to export XML from Fincalcut Pro without open the Application?

By XML I mean .fcpxml.

Why? Cause I want to do automate export and process the data programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, but you can automate opening the program, and exporting the XML.

Comment: An answer is usually just more than "yes you can" you need to cite references, code, suggestions on where to look etc.

Comment: @SteveChambers I am suggesting a workaround. But often the guy is looking for a specific solution for another reason. If you are interested in this method ask the question. It is not very complicated, it involves Automator and AppleScripting, but we need to understand more, like where is the library, what kind of file is being exported, etc.

Comment: Usually, one line answers are discouraged as they lack detail. the important consideration here is to make your answer helpful for anyone trying to do the same thing, even years down the road. I am by no means an authority on FCP or here on AD and if my comments or voting is considered incorrect by another mod they can correct me, delete my comment or remove any votes I made. I offered my opinion which you or anyone is welcome to disagree with or correct. Until that happens, I will stand by my original comment

Comment: @SteveChambers maybe you are right but I won't build the whole code without the guy making sure he wants to follow that path. Perhaps I could just comment instead of answering, but I really think that the real answer for his question is "NO YOU CAN'T". Years to go people can ask for the alternative solution themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Any method of automating FCP would require it to be running. There's no way for FCP to process files without its code executing.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. But again, its very simple to automate opening the program and exporting the XML, closing afterwards. It will take more time and consume memory, but it is what it is.